# Publish/Unpublish dialog not automatically closing when publishing/unpublishing a single item using the "Publish From Publishing Queue" extension

Tags: 2011, publishing

We have downloaded and deployed the '[Publish from Publishing Queue](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/publishfrompublishingqueue.aspx)' extension for Tridion 2011 SP1 CMS product from SDL Tridion World.

The extension publishes and unpublishes items from the Publishing Queue properly but we are facing one problem with the extension's popup window:

When a user selects a single item from the publishing queue and then either publishes or unpublishes the item using the extension, the popup window the extension opens to allow the user to select the Publishing target and settings does not close when the user clicks the publish/unpublish button. Instead, the user has to manually close the popup window in this case. The selected item does publish/unpublish properly.

It seems it could be issue in JavaScript files in the extension i.e.
`\PublishFromPublishingQueue\Scripts\Command\Publish.js`
`\PublishFromPublishingQueue\Scripts\Commands\UnPublish.js` but I am not sure. Could anybody please help on this?

**Note:**
The publish/unpublish window does close properly when multiple content items are selected from the queue and submitted for publishing/unpublishing at the same time using the extension.

Comment: Welcome to the Tridion Stack Exchange site! I have edited your question slightly to hopefully make it a little clearer. If you disagree with my edits please feel free to revert them

Answer (score 5):

The [extension](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/publishfrompublishingqueue.aspx) indeed contained an issue when selecting single items, this was introduced in version 1.2 (which enabled multiple item selection).

Last week the extension has been updated to version 1.3 (by Sebastien PRAT) which should fix this issue, so make sure you download the [1.3 version](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/images/Publish%20from%20Publishing%20Queue%20v1.3_tcm89-19495.zip) of the extension.

*Please note the 1.3 version is configured for SDL Tridion 2013, so to make it work on 2011, you should change the `..\Themes\Carbon\Publishing.css` file and use the commented out values for background-image and background-position.*

Comment: Thanks for providing details. We have installed the 1.3 version extension only. Still we have same issue persists.  The publish window is not closing. It remains open after select  the target type and clicking on the publish button

Comment: Then I'm unable to help you atm, I have it running fine on 2013 myself, and Sebastien told me that it worked on 2011. So I have no clue why it wouldn't work for you.

Comment: We are getting the flollowing javascript error

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; FunWebProducts; BTRS122412; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; FunWebProducts)
Timestamp: Tue, 27 Aug 2013 09:22:01 UTC


Message: 'length' is null or not an object
Line: 513
Char: 2311
Code: 0
URI: http://wincms-utvikling.telenor.no/WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/Popups/PublishQueue/PublishQueue_v6.1.0.55920.4_.aspx?mode=js

Comment: @ParameswarA it's better if you edit your question and add the error in there. As I said, I don't see that error so I don't know how to fix it either, the length is used in several places in the Javascript.

Comment: Did you update the `modification` count in the config? It is in the confile file located `%TRIDION_HOME%\web\WebUI\WebRoot\Configuration\System.config`, try updating the `modification` count and refresh your browser. e.g.; `<server version="6.1.0.55920" modification="7">` , you increment +1 to your existing value in my example it is 7.

Comment: I didn't update the <server version="6.1.0.55920" modification="7">- let me modify then will let you know

Comment: I confirm that your error "Message: 'length" is null or not an object' should be fixed in version 1.3. Could you try to increment your modification number and/or could you clean your browser cache ?

Comment: Thanks to everyone. The latest 1.3 version resolves the issue. I have deployed 1.3 version and increased the modification number.

Comment: Thanks for the update @ParameswarA, could you accept this answer so it's clear for future reference?

Comment: Yes. it resolves the issue. Thanks a lot once again for your support.